# .NET WEB API WITH ANGULAR : Unable to navigate to websites by reading data from the server

Tags: angular, hyperlink, navigation

I bring data from the server to the client
And in the model I have a url I want to navigate with the url to websites

The problem is, when I click on the link, it redirects me to the page and does not direct me to the site:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc6oh.png)

For example:

```
"id": 1,
"name": "Google",
"url": "www.google.com",
```

By click a link I want to navigate to Google

Model:

```
export default class Site{
  id: number = -1;
  name: string = '';
  url: string = '';
}
```

components.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  sites: Site[] = [];

  constructor(private siteService:SiteService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.GetSites();
  }

  GetSites() {
    this.siteService.GetSites()
    .subscribe((sites) => {
        this.sites = sites;
      });
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of sites; let i = index">
  <div>Id: {{item.id}}</div>
  <div>Name: {{item.name}}</div>
  <a href="item.url">{{item.url}}</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently passing the plain string "item.url" as the URL to the anchor tag. If you want to pass the attribute of your JSON object to the anchor tag, you should include brackets (`[]`) in order to bind your object attribute to it:

```
<a [href]="item.url">{{item.url}}</a>
```

**Edit after feedback in comments**
You should also include the protocol in your `url` attribute, e.g. changing

```
"url": "www.google.com",
```

to

```
"url": "http://www.google.com",
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me what you wrote I also tried it before

Comment: Have you tried adding `http://` to the beginning of your URL, so that your browser knows that you are trying to open a website?

Comment: change ur comment i will vote you